# Prevent R output getting syntax highlighted in knitted Rmd?

Tags: r-markdown

When I knit an Rmd file with code that produces output, both the code AND the output have syntax highlighting applied.

[image]

Is there a way to prevent the highlighting being applied to the output? I just want to have the code highlighted.

Comment: Add a code, how we can reproduce it?

Answer (score 0):

OK, I have partially solved this. I had `collapse=T` in my knit settings, which means all code and output is smushed into a single html element and everything gets styled. I think this is probably still undesirable — collapse=F should just mean 2 elements, one for the code and one for the results, each with a different css class.